# Sharinpix Mass Download - Alternative

Tags: visual-workflow, images, screen-flow

Our org uses SharinPix to upload images to Opportunities, Tasks & Events. When we initially switched over to SharinPix, we needed a way to view these images in a user-friendly way (mainly for client visibility). To facilitate that, I designed a flow to populate the Download Link field of the SharinPix Image record with it's details (Account, task, date etc) so that, when downloaded, it would be named according to it's details rather than IMG_0057 or something.

Then, I run a separate screen flow that cycles through SharinPix Image records and opens the download link of each in a background tab (essentially downloading hundreds of images within a few minutes), then marking that record as downloaded. The files are then sorted by powershell scripts into folder structures. This has been working well, except my screen flow to download images is limited to roughly 500 at a time (otherwise the "Apex CPU Time Limit Exceeded" error occurs).

I am wondering if there is an alternative way you would suggest to download more images at once, or even ideally, automatically? To have the images named correctly (and then sorted by powershell into their proper folder structures), the download link on the record has to be used. The built-in SharinPix tools to mass download only allow you to download images with their original names which isn't very useful.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.